# Rubyを用いたGmail(SMTP)のメール送信時にSSLエラーが発生するようになった

Tags: ruby, gmail

Rubyを用いてGmailアカウントのメール送信を行っています。
これまで機能していたのですが、本日以下のエラーが発生し、送信できなくなりました。
おそらくGmail側の問題ではないかと考えていますが、発生原因等わかりましたらお伺いしたく質問させていただきます。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A
```

Comment: エラーメッセージだけではなく、関連するソースコードも質問に含めておいた方が回答も付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: [OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814210)